# Storing values from a file into an array with malloc

Tags: c, malloc

for an assignment I am meant to store values from a file into an array using malloc. The code compiles but stays stuck in the terminal when I execute it. I thought that `i` was not storing the value from the file but that is working fine. I think I'm using the array incorrectly.

Thank you.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    double* arrayPtr = malloc( 10* sizeof(double));
    char lines[128]; //the lines of the txt file
    int i;  
    FILE* file; 
    file = fopen("TriData1.txt", "r");
    int count = 0;
    while (fgets(lines, 128, file))
    { 
        scanf(lines, "%d", &i);
        scanf(" %le", &arrayPtr[i]);
        printf(" %d\n", i);
        printf("line %d: %f\n", (count + 1), arrayPtr[count])
        count++;
    }
free(arrayPtr);

return 0;


}
```

Comment: `scanf(lines, "%d", &i);` This should use `sscanf`, I think. And in other places too. `scanf` is expecting things from standard input.

Comment: What happens when count reaches 10 and beyond?

Comment: @wildplasser I think I worded my question incorrectly. When I execute the code the terminal just stays in place and nothing is printed. When I commented out the array to see if _I_ was the issue the code executed and printed the values correctly.

Comment: As already pointed out - `scanf` does exactly "wait for input form stdin". So it looks like you are incorrectly using that and it should be `sscanf` instead. Also, the comment about the array is pointing out a different (but important) issue - your code is inherently unsafe as it will overflow the array if the file contains more than 10 lines.

Comment: @kaylum ah okay, that makes sense. The program is overflowing. How would I prevent this? sorry I'm still getting used to c.

Comment: I'm not sure you are understanding - the specific problem you are asking about is a result of using `scanf` instead of `sscanf`. You have not acknowledged that so it's not clear if you are understanding that point.

Comment: The overflow is a seperate problem. To prevent it you either add an extra condition to the `while` loop to stop if it reaches 10 lines or pre-read the file to work out how many lines there are before doing the array allocation.

Comment: @kaylum I forgot that `i` was the value and not the line count sorry. I should have named them correctly sorry. I replaced both `scanf` lines with `sscanf(lines ," %lf", &arrayPtr[count]);` and the code is running as expected. Thank you all for highlighting my mistake.